# Read .xml file from project directory in Xamarin project

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have difficulty in reading the .xml file from Xamarin project. Whenever I debug my code I get below error

Could not find a part of the path "/storage/emulated/0/Xml/SupportedTypes.xml".

Below is the code what I am using

```
        public static void Initialize(ConnectedDeviceCommType type)
        {
            string fileName = @"Xml\SupportedTypes.xml";
            string filePath = Path.Combine(OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString(), fileName);

            try
            {
                var xml = XDocument.Load(filePath);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string st = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

I have read that in some of the blogs that they say the .xml file needs to add to the Asset folder but in my case, I don't have any Asset folder in my project and The project I am trying to load is not an activity as well.

So can you please tell me is there any approach to read XML files directly in XAMARIN?

Comment: Check this.                                                                                                            
  <Base namespace>.<RelativePathInProject>.<FileName>

So if your resource is located in "Resources/Xml/", and your default project namespace is "SampleApp.Sample",the resource name is :

"SampleApp.Sample.Resources.Xml.MyXml.xml"

Comment: I tried what you asked but it did not work, still throwing exception. I have checked the value during debug time and the value it is displaying is 
"/storage/emulated/0/[Project namespace]\Xml\SupportedTypes.xml"

Comment: check deleting bin obj and restart VS

Comment: Did you set the XML file build action as EmbeddedResource

Comment: @VinodMG Either embed your XML in the assembly (`EmbeddedResource`) and read it as an embedded resource (personally I do not recommend using embedded resources), or add the XML file to your Android projects' Asset folder (and use Xamarin.Essentials to read it)

Comment: Hi  SushiHangover , I don't have Asset folder in my project and even if I add I cannot use it because the project is not deriving from an activity class .

Comment: @Prasanth , I have tried by setting XML file build action as EmbeddedResource but did not work got the same below error
"Could not find a part of the path "/storage/emulated/0/Xml/SupportedTypes.xml"."

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it work Thanks to Dimitris.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/files?tabs=windows

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand why you want to keep your xml file on your directrory. Because ,if you release your application, you probably won't set up the same directory structure as development. I suggest putting the files in the same folder as the application. Below the code can helps you to access your xml file from directory.

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "SupportedTypes.xml");
```

Comment: Hi Devlst,

I have also tried the way you suggested but no luck, it is throwing exception